# Is it possible to patch Kubernetes Objects with Helm 3 the way we can do using kubectl patch command?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubectl, helm3

Is it possible to patch Kubernetes Objects with Helm 3 the way we can do using kubectl patch command as suggested on this website https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/

kubectl patch deployment patch-demo --patch "$(cat patch-file.yaml)"

Thanks
Anil

Comment: [helm doc 3-way-strategic-merge-patches](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/changes_since_helm2/#improved-upgrade-strategy-3-way-strategic-merge-patches)

Comment: thank you for the quick prompt @z.x , but my question should have been how to do a helm patch with a given patch spec, there is no Helm patch but just upgrade

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Helm does not give any such feature out of the box and suggest post-rendering with other tools like Kustomize:
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/advanced/#post-rendering

Comment: Note here's a guide of how to use helm's post rendering feature with Kustomize
https://gist.github.com/neoakris/edc0642a088be2cdc4f5ffe8d90ef5ca  (I made it after I constantly heard about it but never saw any in depth / good how to guides on the topic)